# Finding $N$ when sum is given

Tags: sequences-and-series, cubics

$1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + \cdots + N^2 = S$

Given $S$

How to find $N$.

The Formula to Find $S$ from $N$ is:

$S = \frac{N(N+1)(2N+1)}6$

so this gives me a cubic equation:

$2N^3 + 3N^2 + N = 6S$

So, how to solve this, because in synthetic division we have
to know one of the roots but many times its not possible.

ps: I know I could have asked the last part directly but I gave the full scenario so that 
    if there is some other method then that is also answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$N^3<3S<(N+1)^3$, and $N$ is an integer.

Comment: Could you add the derivation?

Comment: $N^3<N^3+\frac32N^2+\frac12N=3S<N^3+3N^2+3N+1=(N+1)^3$

Comment: The the body for the OP :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the derivation; nor what 'the the body' means.

Comment: I mean add your method on how to arrive to this result to your answer.

Comment: @Michael.So basically we have to find 3*S and then its cubeRoot and thats our N.

Comment: Yes, that's right.